# Pandas how to treat Series with an 'object' dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas version '0.12.0'. I have a dataframe as below. The dtype of the `id` series was initially float but I have been told that it can contain Strings as well so my code needs to cater for that possibility. So the current dtype of `id` is object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [123,512,'zhub1', 12354.3, 129, 753, 295, 610],
                    'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                            'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                    'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                        'triangular','round','triangular']
                    },  columns= ['id','colour', 'shape'])

df.dtypes
 ->id        object
 ->colour    object
 ->shape     object
 ->dtype: object
```

However, checking for a value in `id` or making 'equal to' conditions using the contents of `id` does not work:

```
'zhub1' in df.id
 ->False 
123 in df.id
 ->False 
df.ix[df.id=='zhub1']
 ->Empty DataFrame
 ->Columns: [id, colour, shape]
 ->Index: []
```

I also tried to convert the dtype of `id` to `str` but it does not help:

```
df.id = df.id.astype(str)
```

I do not know how I should treat `id` at this point since I do not understand how the `object` dtype behaves in this context. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your pandas version? mine is 0.13.1 and my answer works fine for string and number boolean criteria

Comment: Also there is an error in your dataframe creation code remove the empty value in your list -> `129, , 753` of data on first line

Comment: Thank you, Corrected. I was looking into adding a Null value (that is why `id` was of type float and not int to start with) but then could not figure out how to represent a null entry.

Comment: You can use `NaN` or `np.NaN` for empty values, note that this requires a different comparison for `NaN` values e.g. `df[pd.isnull(df.id)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
In [41]:

df[df.id.isin(['zhub1'])]
Out[41]:
      id colour       shape
2  zhub1  white  triangular

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

or better:

```
In [42]:

df[df.id == 'zhub1']
Out[42]:
      id colour       shape
2  zhub1  white  triangular

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

integer comparison also works:

```
In [43]:

df[df.id == 123]
Out[43]:
    id colour  shape
0  123  black  round

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I use 0.12.0 (updated question) and these operations do not work?

Comment: @Zhubarb this may be a bug, I don't have 0.12.0 installed to compare, can you upgrade?